# Python Time Series comparing values

Tags: python, time-series

I have a **time series** with a time stamp (first column) and several integer data columns.

Time     Country 1     Country 2   Country 3

12:00       10.05        25.25        35.40

11:59       11.12        28.33         35.10

11:58         12.18       21.70          37.22

11:57        11.70         21.60           30.20

... ... ... ...

My aim is to output the message "Hit" if and only if the following 2 conditions are BOTH (at the same time) satisfied:

1) The value in cell (row 2, column 3) **is equal to** the value in cell (row 3, column 3)

2) The value in both of the aforementioned cells ends either with .00 **or** 0.20 **or** 0.50 **or** 0.85

So for example, say the value of cell (row 2, column 3) was **18.85** and the value of cell (row 3, column 3) was **18.85**, there would be a hit (as both are the same and both end in .85). But if they both were 18.66, there would be no output as only condition 1 is fulfilled, but condition 2 is not.

I'm new to Python and appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: How is this data stored? Is it in a text file? Excel doc?

Comment: I receive it through an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is stored in a excel file:

> Note: if the excel file has more than one sheet, use
>
> ```py
> sheet = wb["your_sheet_name"]
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```py
> sheet = wb.active
> ```

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('your_file.xlsx')
# print(wb)
sheet = wb.active
#print(dir(sheet))

cell1 = sheet.cell(2,3).value
cell2 = sheet.cell(3,3).value
if cell1 == cell2 and cell1:
  loc = str(cell1).index('.')
  if str(cell1)[loc+1:] in ['00','20','50','85']:
    print('Hit!')
```

Or, if in a text file:

> Note: this assumes there is a line of blank text between each row!

```py
with open('your_file.txt','r') as data:
  d = data.read()
  cell1 = d.split('\n')[2].split(' ')[2]
  cell2 = d.split('\n')[4].split(' ')[2]
  cell1 = float(cell1)
  cell2 = float(cell2)

  if cell1 == cell2:
    loc = str(cell1).index('.')
    if str(cell1)[loc+1:] in ['00','20','50','85']:
      print("Hit")
```

Comment: I found out that I receive the data in JSON format.
I use df = pd.DataFrame(data) to convert it into a data frame and I use cell1 = df.iat[2,3]

Comment: would you know how to solve the following problem too? @Anon
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287698/python-dataframe-count-occurrences-in-a-specified-range-not-axis